# Can anyone explain this code? "Chef and Dolls"(Problem Code: MISSP) on codechef.com. got it from some one else

Tags: c, xor

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) 
{
    int t,n,a,res;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        res=0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        while(n--)
        { 
            scanf("%d",&a);
            res^=a;
        }
        printf("%d\n",res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:
1
3
1
2
1

Output:2

Input:
1
9
1
2
3
4
5
1
4
3
2

Output:5

The objective is to find the odd one that has no pair in the input, the first line is the number of test cases, the second line is the size of the data set. I don't understand how its giving the correct result.

I did the same question in a different manner->

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int T;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    while(T--)
    {
        int n,t[100001]={0},p;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int d[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&d[i]);
            t[d[i]]++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(t[d[i]]%2==1)
            {
                printf("%d\n",d[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works but I don't understand how the first one works....

Comment: It's using bitwise-XOR.  The bitwise-OR of a value with itself is zero, so all paired values cancel out, leaving only the unpaired value (assuming there is only one).

Comment: Try it for yourself.  XOR is commutative and associative, so `1^2^3^4^5^1^4^3^2` = `1^1^2^2^3^3^4^4^5` = `(1^1)^(2^2)^(3^3)^(4^4)^5` = `0^0^0^0^5` = `5`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. A question asking to explain code is [generally too broad for the format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894); there isn't a proper way to answer "I don't understand how it works" because there is no way to understand **why you don't already understand it**.

Answer (score -1):

**Original:**

You are correct to wonder ...

The XOR version does *not* work. It *can* work for certain inputs, but does *not* work in the general case.

**Edit:**

However, per Tom [thanks] (and a reread of the problem), we *always* have the "certain inputs".

Here are the additional rules:

1. The total number of dolls *must* be *odd*
2. Only *one* doll does *not* have a *pair*

So, we *always* have [even if the list is *not* sorted], the equivalent of the following [sorted] list:

```
X A A B B C C D D ...
```

where `X` is the "odd doll" and (e.g.) `A`, `B`, ... are the "other" dolls.

Any value XORed with itself is 0. So, all the pairs will cancel each other out (regardless of the order).

Thus, the above list is the equivalent of:

```
X 0 0 0 0 0
```

So, only `X` will remain.

I've revised the `dotest` script below. And, adjusted the test data.

---

Here is the cleaned up XOR source:

```
// xor.c -- XOR version (other) -- does not work

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int t, n, a, res;

    FILE *fin;
    if (argc < 2)
        fin = stdin;
    else
        fin = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    fscanf(fin,"%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        res = 0;
        fscanf(fin,"%d", &n);
        while (n--) {
            if (fscanf(fin,"%d", &a) != 1) {
                printf("premature EOF\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            res ^= a;
            dbgprt("DBG res=%d a=%d\n",res,a);
        }
        printf("%d\n", res);
    }

    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is your [cleaned up] frequency table source:

```
// freq.c -- frequency counting (OP's code)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     printf(_fmt)
#else
#define dbgprt(_fmt...)     do { } while (0)
#endif

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int T;

    FILE *fin;
    if (argc < 2)
        fin = stdin;
    else
        fin = fopen(argv[1],"r");

    fscanf(fin,"%d", &T);
    while (T--) {
        int n,
         t[100001] = { 0 }, p;
        fscanf(fin,"%d", &n);
        int d[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (fscanf(fin,"%d", &d[i]) != 1) {
                printf("premature EOF\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            t[d[i]]++;
            dbgprt("scanf: i=%d d=%d t=%d\n",i,d[i],t[d[i]]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            dbgprt("final: i=%d d=%d t=%d\n",i,d[i],t[d[i]]);
            if (t[d[i]] % 2 == 1) {
                printf("%d\n", d[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is a perl script that generates test cases:

**Edit:** Revised to add the restriction of a odd number of dolls.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# dotest2 -- run chef and dolls test
#
# options:
#   "-C" -- count of numbers per test
#   "-T" -- number of tests (DEFAULT: 10)
#   "-R" -- random number seed (DEFAULT: 12345)
#   "-e" -- stop on test error
#   "-gdb" -- run program under gdb
#
# arguments:
#   1-- list of programs to test (DEFAULT: *.c)

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;

    optdcd(\@argv,"opt_gdb","opt_T","opt_C","opt_R","opt_e");

    $opt_R //= 12345;
    srand($opt_R);
    zprtx("R=%d\n",$opt_R);

    $datfile = "biginp";
    zprtx("input=%s\n",$datfile);

    open($xfout,">$datfile") or
        die("unable to open '$datfile' -- $!\n");

    $opt_T //= int(rand(10)) + 1;
    outf("%d\n",$opt_T);
    zprtx("T=%d\n",$opt_T);

    $cmax = 100000;
    $opt_C //= $cmax;
    $opt_C = $cmax
        if ($opt_C > $cmax);

    for ($tcur = 1;  $tcur <= $opt_T;  ++$tcur) {
        dogen();
    }

    close($xfout);

    opendir($xfdir,".");
    while (1) {
        $pgm = readdir($xfdir);
        last unless (defined($pgm));

        push(@pgm,$pgm)
            if ($pgm =~ s/[.]c$//);
    }
    close($xfdir);

    push(@argv,@pgm)
        if (@argv <= 0);

    foreach $pgm (@argv) {
        dopgm();
    }
}

sub dogen
{
    my(@dup);
    my($ocnt);

    $arrcnt = int(rand($opt_C)) + 1;
    $arrcnt |= 1;
    outf("\n%d\n",$arrcnt);

    # get the unique value
    $single = int(rand(100001));

    # get the index to inject
    ###$injidx = int(rand($arrcnt));

    outf(" %d\n",$single);
    ++$ocnt;

    zprtx("dogen: single=%d arrcnt=%d\n",$single,$arrcnt);
    push(@exp,$single);

    $npair = int($arrcnt / 2);

    for ($idx = 0;  $idx < $npair;  ++$idx) {
        while (1) {
            $dup = int(rand(100001));
            last if ($dup != $single);
        }
        push(@dup,$dup);
    }

    for ($idx = 0;  ;  ++$idx) {
        last if ($ocnt >= $arrcnt);
        $dup = $dup[$idx % $npair];
        outf(" %d\n",$dup);
        ++$ocnt;
    }
}

sub dopgm
{

    zprtx("\n");
    zprtx("dopgm: %s\n",$pgm);

    zprtx("cc ...\n");
    $code = doexec("cc","-g","-o",$pgm,"$pgm.c");
    exit(1) if ($code);

    if ($opt_gdb) {
        dogdb();
    }
    else {
        docmp();
    }
}

sub docmp
{

    zprtx("run $pgm $datfile ...\n");

    @act = (`./$pgm $datfile`);
    $status = $?;
    $code = $status >> 8;

    zprtx("%d lines\n",scalar(@act));

    if ($code) {
        zprtx("fault code=%d status=%8.8X\n",$code,$status);
        exit(1);
    }

    $idx = -1;
    foreach $exp (@exp) {
        ++$idx;

        $act = $act[$idx];
        chomp($act);

        $pass = ($act == $exp);

        printf("dopgm: %s exp=%d act=%d -- %s\n",
            $pgm,$exp,$act,$pass ? "PASS" : "FAIL");

        if ($opt_e) {
            exit(1) unless ($pass);
        }
    }
}

sub dogdb
{

    zprtx("gdb ...\n");
    open($xfgdb,">cmds") or
        die("dogdb: unable to open 'cmds' -- $!\n");

    printf($xfgdb "set args %s\n",$datfile);

    close($xfgdb);

    doexec("gdb","-x","cmds","./$pgm");
}

# optdcd -- decode command line options
sub optdcd
{
    my(@syms) = @_;
    my($argv);
    my($arg);
    my($sym,$val,$match);

    $argv = shift(@syms);

    # get options
    while (@$argv > 0) {
        $arg = $argv->[0];
        last unless ($arg =~ /^-/);

        shift(@$argv);

        $match = 0;
        foreach $sym (@syms) {
            $opt = $sym;
            $opt =~ s/^opt_/-/;

            if ($arg =~ /^$opt(.*)$/) {
                $val = $1;

                $val =~ s/^=//;
                $val = 1
                    if ($val eq "");

                $$sym = $val;
                $match = 1;
                last;
            }
        }

        sysfault("optdcd: unknown option -- '%s'\n",$arg)
            unless ($match);
    }
}

sub outf
{

    printf($xfout @_);
}

sub doexec
{

    $cmd = join(" ",@_);
    system($cmd);
    $code = $? >> 8;

    $code;
}

sub zprtx
{
    printf(@_);
}
```

---

Here is the output of `./dotest2 -C20 -T10`:

```
R=12345
input=biginp
T=10
dogen: single=91919 arrcnt=5
dogen: single=90649 arrcnt=15
dogen: single=12698 arrcnt=21
dogen: single=26591 arrcnt=13
dogen: single=2026 arrcnt=11
dogen: single=29902 arrcnt=1
dogen: single=44366 arrcnt=21
dogen: single=12315 arrcnt=15
dogen: single=55435 arrcnt=19
dogen: single=11214 arrcnt=11

dopgm: freq
cc ...
run freq biginp ...
10 lines
dopgm: freq exp=91919 act=91919 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=90649 act=90649 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=12698 act=12698 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=26591 act=26591 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=2026 act=2026 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=29902 act=29902 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=44366 act=44366 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=12315 act=12315 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=55435 act=55435 -- PASS
dopgm: freq exp=11214 act=11214 -- PASS

dopgm: xor
cc ...
run xor biginp ...
10 lines
dopgm: xor exp=91919 act=91919 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=90649 act=90649 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=12698 act=12698 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=26591 act=26591 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=2026 act=2026 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=29902 act=29902 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=44366 act=44366 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=12315 act=12315 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=55435 act=55435 -- PASS
dopgm: xor exp=11214 act=11214 -- PASS
```

Here is the generated input file:

```
10

5
 91919
 20684
 72478
 20684
 72478

15
 90649
 34796
 85788
 41518
 19416
 68561
 52438
 15963
 34796
 85788
 41518
 19416
 68561
 52438
 15963

21
 12698
 433
 38269
 25079
 65529
 53449
 60997
 28786
 90927
 73613
 12110
 433
 38269
 25079
 65529
 53449
 60997
 28786
 90927
 73613
 12110

13
 26591
 94536
 42469
 24835
 67730
 7120
 45574
 94536
 42469
 24835
 67730
 7120
 45574

11
 2026
 88618
 65458
 55970
 98505
 33945
 88618
 65458
 55970
 98505
 33945

1
 29902

21
 44366
 12912
 91504
 38642
 3043
 18444
 93569
 48079
 59784
 43615
 10501
 12912
 91504
 38642
 3043
 18444
 93569
 48079
 59784
 43615
 10501

15
 12315
 67212
 3399
 96444
 1952
 4466
 42123
 76422
 67212
 3399
 96444
 1952
 4466
 42123
 76422

19
 55435
 61717
 64651
 38567
 90212
 32288
 42315
 45495
 57224
 4846
 61717
 64651
 38567
 90212
 32288
 42315
 45495
 57224
 4846

11
 11214
 84260
 38638
 3674
 74480
 50266
 84260
 38638
 3674
 74480
 50266
```

Comment: The XOR code works for the stated problem, where all of the numbers come in pairs but one.  For what values do you think the XOR version doesn't work?  Show them.

Comment: A lot of your input sequences are invalid.  There should always be an odd number of values for each case:  two instances of each except for the unpaired value.  Read the problem description.  The XOR version is known to work correctly on correct input.

Comment: Here's a link to the problem description:  [Chef and Dolls Problem](https://www.codechef.com/problems/MISSP).  Hopefully this will help you understand why the XOR solution works.  The only real problem with the XOR version is that it doesn't detect invalid input.  Ideally it would give an error if the input didn't conform to the stated requirements.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks. I _did_ have a copy of the problem, but, [obviously] I missed the requirement that the total number of dolls must be odd. I've revised my answer and added an explanation as to why the XOR code works.